# Why does hand lotion make me feel thirsty?

Tags: water, hand, hydration, topical-cream-gel

I noticed a few years ago that when I use hand lotion, I get thirsty. Is there any medical/scientific reason this happens?

Answer (score -1):

No, there's no scientific or medical reason why applying hand lotion makes one thirsty. Personally, I think its not the hand lotion making you thirsty, it could be something else.